# Re-applying for a Schengen visa, difference between 'revoked' and 'annulled'

Tags: visas, schengen, terminology

I applied for a Schengen visa 2 years ago and got it, but the visa was revoked because I tried to travel to another Schengen country, which I wasn't allowed to due to the limitations on my Schengen visa.

I was giving some days to vacate the country, which I did. I wasn't deported – it's a voluntary departure – but the earlier visa given was canceled.

**Since my earlier circumstance has changed, can I re-apply for a new Schengen visa and this time?  Or am I going to be refused because of my earlier visa revocation, which I still have on my passport?**

I am only visiting the country that is going to issue the Schengen visa. The earlier visa was issued by the Latvian embassy; now I intend to travel to Estonia as a tourist again.

Comment: *"am I going to be refused"* - It's impossible for us to predict what the visa authorities will do. They will look at your previous history and make a decision whether to grant you a new visa or not. We do not have the information they have about your history, so any answer you get from the internet is going to just be a guess.

Comment: @GregHewgill maybe there are some policies, he's asking about that.

Comment: It does not guarantee you will be refused, but you will probably face much greater scrutiny when applying for the visa. Be sure that all of your documents and finances are in order.

Comment: What citizenship do you have?

Comment: @GregHewgill you can probably turn that into an answer, frankly.

Comment: Could you provide some details on your earlier visa? What do you mean by "limitations on my Schengen visa"? Was it a single entry visa? What was the reason provided for the revocation (you are supposed to get a standard form specifying a reason)?

Answer (score 8):

In Schengen parlance, "revoking" means that the conditions for issuing the visa were not met anymore when you tried to cross the border. This is distinct from an "annulment", which should only happen if there are reasons to believe that the visa should never have been issued in the first place. The latter is obviously more serious as it implies that you lied or committed fraud to get the visa. Not so for a revocation (which is good for you).

But even an annulment, let alone a revocation or a mere refusal, does not legally bar you from receiving a visa in the future so your application should not in any event be refused *because* of that. The consulate will however be aware of it (from the stamps in your passport but also through their databases) and will presumably review your new application a little more carefully than others. Beyond that, it's impossible to guess what the outcome will be without a lot more details (and there would still be no way to be certain even if we knew all the details).

Answer (score 2):

Refusal of earlier visa doesn't mean you will not be given a visa this time. As I read in some of the comments, yes the scrutiny will be more than a normal person and just make sure your documents are just spot on. Your margin of error is less this time. Do not make fake bookings. They might actually call your hotel and check if you have actually booked it.

Comment: Revoking/cancelling is not the same than refusing an application.