# Does a revoked visa make you prone to refusal in future?

Tags: schengen, study

I have a revoked national visa from a Schengen country. I couldn't reach there within the university's deadline.

The VIS mentioned "requirements are not being fulfilled anymore to grant visa." Will this cause refusals in future?

And what is the difference between annulled and revoked visa?

Comment: For one part, please see previous question [Re-applying for a Schengen visa, difference between 'revoked' and 'annulled'](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26898/re-applying-for-a-schengen-visa-difference-between-revoked-and-annulled).

Comment: I think the question Weather Vane is linking to is close enough for this question to be closed as a duplicate. At least Relaxed's answer to the other question answers this question very well too.